# docker-compose - Expose linked service port

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a SonarQube container backed by a MySQL database container.
My docker-compose.yml:

```
sonar:
  environment:
    - SONARQUBE_USER=sonar
    - SONARQUBE_PASSWORD=sonar
    - SONARQUBE_DATABASE=sonar
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
  build: .
  ports:
    - "19000:9000"
    - "19306:3306"
  links:
    - db
db:
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-secret
    - MYSQL_USER=sonar
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sonar
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=sonar
  image: mysql
```

In the `ports` section I'm trying to expose both port 9000 from SonarQube (web interface) and port 3306 (MySQL connection).

Is there any way to expose a port from a linked service (such as `db` in this case) from the "main" container e.g. `sonar`?

EDIT: Just to better explain my needs, I want to expose both ports to my `localhost`. I need access to both ports from my machine, as I SonarQube runner needs access to the database and I want to run some queries in the database too, *from my machine, not inside another container*.

Comment: I understand now. But why not simply map the `db` `EXPOSE`'d port to the host like you did for Sonar? Sonar will still use the `EXPOSE` `db` port directly, but your query from localhost will use the port value that you will have specified in the `db/ports` section (see my edited answer below)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to: an [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) port from one service is directly visible from another (linking to the first).

No port mapping necessary (as you do for 9000 from SonarQube and 3306)
Port mapping is necessary for accessing a container from the host.
But from container to [a (linked) container](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables) (both managed by the same docker daemon), any port declared in [`EXPOSE` in its `Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) is directly accessible.

> I want to expose both ports to my localhost. I need access to both ports from my machine, as I SonarQube runner needs access to the database

Well then,... the `db` section should have its own port mapping section:

```
db:
  ports:
    - "xxx:yyyy"
```

Comment: For some reason I tried that and I didn't work. I guess the rest of my configuration was quite wrong, but now works like a charm. Tks

Comment: Is this true when docker is running in a virtualenv? I can't seem to get this to work